# InputStream.read() returning -1 after PrintWriter

Tags: java, file, sockets, printwriter

The server & client code below attempts to send over a file with its name:

- The client sends over the *file name* using a PrintWriter which flushes after **println** is called. After, the client sends over the file contents using common method of a while loop that reads the file until InputStream.read returns -1.
- The server reads the *file name* using a BufferedReader (**readLine**). After, the server reads the file contents using that same while loop.

**The issue is**: When the server and client programs are executed locally on the same machine (my Windows laptop) everything executes successfully. *However*, when the programs are executed on separate machines on the same network, the server-side ***InputStream.read()*** returns -1.

**I'm not looking for an answer in code.** (I've already rewritten with DataInputStream) I want to know *why* this is the case.

Server:

```
try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3000);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader printIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String name = printIn.readLine();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*16];
        File file = new File(name);
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) != -1) {
            fOut.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        fOut.close();
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Client:

```
try {
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost",3000);
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter printOut = new PrintWriter(out,true);
        printOut.println("old.jar");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*16];
        File file = new File("old.jar");
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        int count;
        while((count = fIn.read(bytes,0, bytes.length)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        fIn.close();
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You can't mix buffered streams or readers on the same socket. The `BufferedReader` will read ahead and consume part of the following file data. You need a different approach for sending tthe filename, that uses the same input stream you're reading the following file data with. `readUTF()/writeUTF()` come to mind.

Comment: Thank you, @EJP. I wasn't aware of the underlying protocol used for sockets.

Comment: @EJP That still doesn't explain why the file is sent over on a local connection. Thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the 'underlying protocol used for sockets'. It has to do with mixing different types of streams when one of them is buffered. As I said. For the reason I said. On a local connection you must be getting different packetizing behaviour so the start of the file data doesn't arrive along with the name.

Comment: @EJP Okay, I understand. So that the question could be answered, I made your comments into an official answer and gave you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments: **"You can't mix buffered streams or readers on the same socket. The BufferedReader will read ahead and consume part of the following file data."**

Therefore, when *InputStream.read()* is called after *BufferedReader.readLine()* the BufferedReader consumes the file data, and so the *InputStream.read()* returns -1.

As to why the code executes successfully on a local connection: **The local connection likely has different packeting behavior than the remote connection**.

(Credit goes to @EJP)